# React Native: how to wait for application window to be present?

Tags: react-native

After upgrade to React Native 0.57.8 from 0.56.0 I get the error "Tried to display alert view but there is no application window" when an alert should be shown on app start up. UI seems to be loading slower than before. To workaround the issue I added a setTimeout for 0.5sec but I don't like this solution and want to check whether application window is present. I'm going to implement a basic "wait for" logic where I will be checking for application window presence every 0.01 sec. Now my question is how to check for its presence?

Btw, not sure if this is related but I also use Wix react native navigation 2

EDIT: Thats's how alert manager checks for it on native side:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAlertManager.m#L93

I just want to do the same from javascript.

Comment: Where are you putting the alert? Can you post your component.

Comment: The app is pretty huge. It would be difficult to strip what you're asking for. I'm not going to refactor the logic for now. What I basically need is if (ApplicationWindow is present) { show alert }. I don't know how to check for this ApplicationWindow. That's basically it.

Comment: Is it within the correct part of the lifecycle? What version of RN are you using? if iOS, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5269 . However this is a certain version of RN. Perhaps try and nested component. However without seeing anything, how can we help you, it may be as simple as incorrect implementation lifecycle? are you calling like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645893/react-native-alertios-error-tried-to-display-alert-view-but-there-is-no-applica .